# How to use Azure DNS server to set local CNAME?

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

As you can't set CNAMES using local hosts file, I needed to setup a simple hosted DNS server we can point at so our team can see a beta version of our system which happens to be on AEM CMS which uses fastly and requires CNAMES to access.

I tried setting up an Azure "DNS Zone"
then I added a "record set" of "mytargetdomain.com" with a CNAME of cdn.adobeaemcloud.com, and one for "www.mytargetdomain.com" to it.

at the top of the resource overview, it shows

```
Name server 1 : ns1-08.azure-dns.com.
etc.
```

If I use ns1-08.azure-dns.com as my dns server, and query mytargetdomain.com it gives me the live A record IP, not the CNAME I just setup.

```
 nslookup mytargetdomain.com ns1-08.azure-dns.com
```

gives:

```
 Server:        ns1-08.azure-dns.com
 Address:   40.90.4.8#53
 *** Can't find mytargetdomain.com: No answer
```

I must admit I don't know much about DNS and SOA etc, but there really isn't anything else which can be configured or edited.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of a record in a DNS zone should ***not*** include the domain name. To create a record called `www.domain.com` in a zone called `domain.com`, the record name should be `www`.

You can create a CNAME record called `www` in your `mytargetdomain.com` zone and set its value to `cdn.adobeaemcloud.com`; this will effectively map `www.mytargetdomain.com` to `cdn.adobeaemcloud.com`.

You can also create a record with an empty name; this will map the domain name itself to a target.
However, this can only be done using A records, not CNAME ones; you can map a domain name to an IP address, but not to another name.

Comment: Boom, works.  Except you cant set CNAMEs for the apex without the www, but we can live with www.